# How to encode string on Python 3.0 and decode it on Python 2.7 correctly over socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I'm writing an online multiple player console game by Python. The server uses Python 3.0 and the client uses Python 2.7(because I want to use my smartphone and I can only find Python 2.7 on it). However, I have trouble converting the encoding of string between server and client.

I wrote two function, `sendData` and `receiveData` to send and receive a string from socket connection. The problem is that when I encode the string `你好` by 'utf-8' on server side and decode it on client side, I got this error on client:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: unexpected end of data

I tried `encode('utf-8')` on both sides or `decode*('utf-8')` on both sides, but both not working. I also tried to use pickle, but got this error on client:

> ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3

So how should I encode and decode the string?

Here is my code for server(Python 3.0, datatrans.py):

```
def sendData(sock, data):
    '''
    Send string through socket.
    '''
    sock.send(struct.pack('Q', len(data)))
    sock.send(bytes(data.encode('utf-8'))) # This might be the cause of the error

def receiveData(sock):
    '''
    Receive object from socket.
    '''
    lengthLeft = struct.unpack('Q', sock.recv(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
    data = bytes()
    while lengthLeft > 0:
        block = sock.recv(lengthLeft)
        data += block
        lengthLeft -= len(block)
    return str(data)
```

The main script for server(Python 3.0):

```
import socket
import threading
import socket
from datatrans import sendData, receiveData
import time

port = int(input('Listen on port：'))

def log(string):
    return '[%s]%s' % (str(time), string)

def handleRequest(sock):
    sendData(sock, '你好')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
s.listen(5)

try:
    while True:
        sock, addr = s.accept()
        print(log('%s entered the game' % str(addr)))
        #print sock.recv(1000)
        threading.Thread(target = handleRequest, args = (sock,)).start()
finally:
    s.close()
```

My code for client is this, with `sendData` and `receiveData` changed a little(Python 2.7):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import socket
import struct

def sendData(sock, data):
    '''
    Send string through socket.
    '''
    sock.send(struct.pack('Q', len(data)))
    sock.send(data)

def receiveData(sock):
    '''
    Receive object from socket.
    '''
    lengthLeft = struct.unpack('Q', sock.recv(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
    data = ''
    while lengthLeft > 0:
        block = sock.recv(lengthLeft)
        data += block
        lengthLeft -= len(block)
    return data.decode('utf-8') # Error comes from here

while True:
    try:
        ip = raw_input('Sever IP:')
        port = int(raw_input('Port:'))

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, port))
    except socket.error as error:
        print('Error while connecting')
        print(error)
        print('')
    else:
        break

while True:
    print(receiveData(s))
```

Also, I'm wondering what should I do when sending a string entered by user from client to the server so that the server won't complain about encoding errors? Python 2.7 uses different encoding on different system, so I have no idea on how to deal with it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one problem that your Python2 program is dealing with Byte strings all the time (that is - not Unicode string) but for the payload you try to decode where you get the error.

If this is a small application, maybe just skip the decode step, and program your client app to deal with utf-8 encoded byte-strings all the time. (But that is not feasible if you have to process text beyond getting input and sending it through the network there).

Now, that is not the source of your `UnidodeDecode` error as you show us - since the Server is correctly encoding the data, and even if it was double-encoding it, this specific error would not happen.

What happens is that on the server side you are calculating the length of the text string - pre-encoding, and then encoding it to UTF-8. With the class of characters you show us in your example, utf-8 takes up to 4 bytes per character.

So, you make a payload announcing you have a length "2" string and then transmit 8 bytes - and the text decoder would need 4 of them to actually transform the character back.

Just rewrite this:

```
def sendData(sock, data):
    '''
    Send string through socket.
    '''
    sock.send(struct.pack('Q', len(data)))
    sock.send(bytes(data.encode('utf-8')))
```

To this:

```
def sendData(sock, data):
    '''
    Send string through socket.
    '''
    encoded_data = data.encode('utf-8')
    sock.send(struct.pack('Q', len(encoded_data)))
    sock.send(bytes(encoded_data))
```

And you should eliminate this main error there.

Also, the last line on the server-site receiver function can't be:
`return str(data)` - make it `return data.decode('utf-8')`  instead.